# HasDbFunction, table value function without a mapped entity class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

Everything I've found so far, if you are calling a table value function the return value must be an IQueryable. For example:

```
public IQueryable<AlbumsByGenre> ufn_AlbumsByGenre_ITVF(int genreId)
    => FromExpression(() => ufn_AlbumsByGenre_ITVF(genreId));
```

Most often when I'm using a table value function the table type that is returns is a DTO. That is, it doesn't match any actual tables in the database. Here is a example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_AlbumsByGenre_ITVF(@GenreId int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN(  
    SELECT 
      ar.ArtistName,
      al.AlbumName,
      g.Genre
    FROM Genres g 
      INNER JOIN Albums al
        ON g.GenreId = al.GenreId 
      INNER JOIN Artists ar 
        ON al.ArtistId = ar.ArtistId
    WHERE g.GenreId = @GenreId
);
```

Creating an entity for the return type results in an unnecessary, unused, and unwanted table in the database. In this instance the table name is "AlbumsByGenre".

Is there any way to have the return type be an unmapped type to prevent the unnecessary table?

Comment: The table is only added to the database if you use migrations. It doesn't *have* to be there because EF won't ever try to query it directly. I think you can even remove it from the generated migration scripts (didn't try, I try to avoid migrations whenever I can).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently (as of EF Core 6.0) the type must be a model type (with or without key). There are plans for [Raw SQL queries for unmapped types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan) for EF Core 7.0 which might or might not allow the mapping you are asking for.

So for now your type must be registered in the model (cannot be unmapped). But creating associated table is not mandatory and can be avoided by configuring it with `ToView(null)`, e.g.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<AlbumsByGenre>()
    .HasNoKey() // keyless
    .ToView(null); // no table or view
```

Comment: Hehe, of course! Made me smile again :)

Answer (score 0):

For me .ToView(null) still generates a table for the AlbumsByGenre.
My workaround is to map this type to the raw SQL query (tested on Entity Framework Core 6.0.9). Here I call the function with default parameters (for the author's case, the NULL value should be then allowed).

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AlbumsByGenre>()
    .HasNoKey()
    .ToSqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ufn_AlbumsByGenre_ITVF(NULL)");
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes just create a class that has `ArtistName`, `AlbumName` and `Genre` however it should not be an `IQueryable` just a `List<AlbumsByGenre>` or `IEnumerable<AlbumsByGenre>` or an `ICollection`.

`IQueryable` is a delayed querybuilder for a table or view.

SQL functions results are not further queryable in SQL Server, so just drop the `IQueryable`.

Comment: I do not follow this answer. `IQueryable` is the right way to define table valued functions, see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping#mapping-a-queryable-function-to-a-table-valued-function).

Comment: @ChineSyndrome you didn't quite understand the question I'm afraid. They don't want the obligatory mapped class in the model.

Comment: They use a Dynamic      type = Dynamic

Comment: DbContext.FromExpression<TResult> Method returns IQueryable<TResult> and requires that TResult is an entity type. If you know of some other way to call a DB function from EF Core please provide a code example.

Comment: *They use a Dynamic type* -- I can't follow. Anyway, a TVF returns a table (hence the name), so the function must return some sort of an enumerable type. And it's `IQueryable` because, contrary to what you say, the result is composable.