# EF Core: filter on converted column

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a `Tags` field (similar to the sample in [Value Conversions->Collection of Primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#collections-of-primitives)):

```cs
public class Asset
{
    ...

    public ICollection<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

In my case, I'm serialising tags to a string of terms separated by spaces:

```cs
builder.Property(e => e.Tags).HasConversion(
    v => string.Join( ' ', v.Distinct() ),
    v => v.Split( ' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ).ToList()
);
```

If I were to write an SQL statement, I can filter terms like so:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Assets 
WHERE Tags LIKE '%tag1%' OR Tags LIKE '%tag2%'
```

Is there a way to achieve the same thing, but using Linq?

The problem is, in the object model I have a collection of strings, but I want to treat the field like it's a single string (in the case of filtering).

The following will not translate into valid SQL:

```cs
var results = context.Assets
                     .Where( x => x.Tags.Contains("tag1") || x.Tags.Contains("tag2") )
                     .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: As I know, properties with converters cannot be used in LINQ queries. So, no.

Comment: See the linked "duplicate" post. In your case, you could use `((string)(object)x.Tags)` for "conversion", and then `.Contains("tag1")` or whatever string operator you want. If you are targeting SqlServer only, then you might utilize `SPLIT_STRING` function as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73089539/string-intersection-using-ef-core-linq-sql-server/73182045#73182045

Comment: Yeah, I just saw the information about the cast! Realised my question should have been can I filter on the provider type rather than the CLR type!

Comment: True. An that's exactly what `(ProviderType)(object)clrTypeValue` trick does.